# Bash Script to output various data about a directory? (Directory owner, number of files, name/size of biggest file)

Tags: linux, shell-script, command-line, oracle-linux

I am still very new to Linux, and I am tasked with writing a bash script that outputs various details inside a menu box. These details include:

```
Directory owner/permissions,
Number of files in directory,
and Name and size of biggest file
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
function show_details(){

read -p "Please enter a path: " path1

cd $path1

ls -ld | > $OUTPUT

ls | wc -l > $OUTPUT

find . -maxdepth 1 -printf '%s %p\n'|sort -nr|head -n 1 > $OUTPUT

display_output 13 25 "Details" 

}
```

It successfully reads the path, as well as outputs name and size of biggest file, but skips the first two. What am I doing wrong that causes the output file to ONLY read the final '> $OUTPUT' with name/biggest file? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Your main issue is what is explained in the duplicate: you should use `>>` instead of `>`. However, there are some other things you should look at: i) don't parse the output of `ls`. See [Greg's Wiki](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). ii) avoid using CAPS for shell variable names. By convention, global environment variables are capitalized and if yours are as well, that can lead to naming collisions. iii) don't ask your user to type a path, read it at launch (`show_details /path` and then use `$1`). iiv) [***always quote your variables***](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/22222).

Comment: This is a really useful tool if you're learning shell scripting (and even if you're an expert): https://www.shellcheck.net/. It will point out errors and bad practices in any script you give it.